# How to read 32-bit PCI bar memory in 64-bit linux kernel environment

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

I want to do I/O on my PCIe device.I am running Ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS with linux kernel 4.4.0

The output of `lspci -v` command is:

```
06:00.0 Unclassified device [00ff]: Device 1aa1:2000 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Device 1aa1:2000
    Physical Slot: 1-4
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at f1008000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Memory at ee000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32M]
    Memory at f100a000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at f0000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at f1000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: my_pci
    Kernel modules: my_pci
```

Clearly, PCI addresses are 32-bit.

I want to know how to use ioread32/iowrite32 functions to read/write into the BAR addresses.
`unsigned char __iomem *mem` types on my machine would be 64-bit and if I use the following say :

```
ioread32(mem + some_offset);
```

The expression `mem + some_offset` would be 64-bit and result into crash.

How would I do the I/O ?

Comment: Bars can'y be just written into, they need to be mapped to virtual memory. the driver normally does it just after initialization. you need to write to that address + the offset.

Comment: @stdcall I know and that's how the things are implemented in source code.
But my question is slightly different- My host machine is running 64-bit Ubuntu with kernel 4.4.0. Looking at my `lspci -v` output, we can see that the PCI bar addresses are 32-bit. So I was wondering/doubtful that the argument to `ioread32` being 64-bit address would result in undefined behaviour.

Comment: Ah.  Got it.  Got an answer for you.

Comment: Is there a kernel command to enable 64 bit BAR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PCI devices you're working with works using 32bit addressing mode.
when your PC enumerates the BARs and writes the physical address onto the BAR. it writes a masked values, only the lower 32 bit of the 64 bit (in host address space)
Print the physical address the OS/BIOS has assigned to this BAR on the driver and compare it.

besides, this is a physical address, so you can't `iowrite` to it anyway.

So I don't really understand your goal.

Comment: That's exactly what I found while printing the addresses. thanks for the answer.